# How to express "to look at more or all sides" and "consider more or all views" for a thing?

Tags: single-word-requests

One commonly looks at something from his own viewpoint.
Sometimes, we suggest somebody look at something from another view or in an overall view.

I hope this could make it clearly.

I want some opposites of 'one-sided'. or something like this.

one side -> on the other hand -> all sides

one view -> multiple view -> all views

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: The idea seems to be "how do you describe a more general outlook on something" but I'm not 100% sure that's the real question.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Neither the question or title are worded well but I understood the question as: "How do I express looking at all sides of argument or debate?"

Comment: This question really needs to be revised completely, I think.

Comment: @MrHen Yes. something like overall?

Comment: @user: I gave my answer to the question. Someone apparently disagrees with it, however.

Comment: MrHen and Kosmonaut said most of it and if you really mean “more or all sides/views” then sorry, you’re on a hiding to nothing. Either “More” or “All” might be fine. Both together simply can’t be done.

“More” might lead to “multiple” and “all” to something like “omnispective” or “omnividentes” but those are constructs; you could as easily make up your own.

The only possible “opposite” of one-sided would “infinite-sided”.

“one side -> on the other hand -> all sides” isn’t a logical progression, nor is “one view -> multiple views -> all views”. Both are merely lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Former American Secretary of Defense, Donald Rumsfeld, once said:

> As we know, there are known knowns. There are things we know we know. 
>   We also know there are known unknowns. That is to say we know there are some things we do not know. 
>   But there are also unknown unknowns, the ones we don't know we don't know.

You can express the need to look at additional 'parameters' or 'options' in many ways.  here are a few that come to mind:

- Have you explored all options?
- What other input parameters does this system accept?
- Have you considered all the alternatives?
- Are there any other choices?
- Do you account for unknowns?
- Have you explored all avenues?
- Have you viewed the problem from all angles?
- Are there more inputs that we haven't covered yet?
- Have all the terms been defined?

Basically, take just about any verb that means 'searching', 'exploring', or 'viewing', and pair it with just about any noun that means 'option', 'path', 'route', 'input', or 'choice'.

Comment: I really can't see the relevance of this answer or the OP's choosing it.

Answer (score 2):

I would choose a word like "analysis" and throw an adjective such as "unbiased" before it.

> This was an unbiased analysis.
>
> His was a multifaceted viewpoint.
>
> We need an impartial outlook.
>
> Look at this more abstractly.

Comment: No. I want some opposites of 'one-sided'. or something like this.

Comment: @user: I added a few more examples. Of note, unbiased _is_ an opposite of one-sided but multifaceted is probably the most direct opposite I can think of.

Comment: +1 for multifaceted, I think it describes the concept very well. Another option, albeit wordier, would be to say "Looking at the situation from multiple points of view...".

Comment: @nico: Yes, multiple points of view is good. A somewhat shorter variation: "Multiple viewpoints" or _extra_, _more_ or any other quantifier would work well.

Comment: @MrHen thank you, MrHen. your answer really helps me. esp. multiface.

Answer (score 0):

open-minded

> If you describe someone as open-minded, you approve of them because
>   they are willing to listen to and consider other people's ideas and
>   suggestions. 
>  He was very open-minded about other people's work.
>   [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/open-minded)