# Is there a word or term that means to consider something from muliple angles or views?

Tags: single-word-requests

Similarly, how does one express holding opposing or considering many options about a problem or opinion?

I am trying to concisely express the ability to consider all sides.

Comment: Do you mean "deliberate"?  - To consider (a matter) carefully and often slowly, as by weighing alternatives.

Comment: Concision does not necessarily mean finding a single word to replace a phrase. "We must consider the matter from all sides" is  a concise statement.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about concision. I'd edit if I knew how.

Comment: You're looking to say "We should ________ the matter" where a single verb is placed in the blank, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put verbs of discussion and thought in the first person, they seem to work. For example, "bandy": "I bandied about the problem."

"Brainstorm", and "puzzle over" also indicate a multi-step process, although not specifically "multi-view".

Also see:
[Word for seeing both sides of an argument](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78066/word-for-seeing-both-sides-of-an-argument)
and
[How to express "to look at more or all sides" and "consider more or all views" for a thing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17409/how-to-express-to-look-at-more-or-all-sides-and-consider-more-or-all-views-f)

Comment: And there it is! Perfect.

"Dialectic - the art or practice of arriving at the truth by the exchange of logical arguments.

The process especially associated with Hegel of arriving at the truth by stating a thesis, developing a contradictory antithesis, and combining and resolving them into a coherent synthesis."

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***Contemplate*** been the first word to come to my mind, and it's meaning is given in [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/contemplate) as:

> VERB
>
> *with object*
>
> 1.1 Think about.
>
> ***she couldn't even begin to contemplate the future***
>
> 1.2 ( *no object* ) Think deeply and at length.
>
> ***he sat morosely contemplating***

Answer (score 0):

Although **circumspect** is used both colloquially and prosaically to mean "considering something for a long time and delaying taking action; being careful or wary," the etymological roots of the word are *circum-* which means around and *-spect* which means to see. So it could be literally translated from its roots to mean seeing around the whole thing.

So actually, **circumspection** may be one of the literal words for that case, although it has a somewhat different meaning in modern usage.

> cir·cum·spec·tion
>
> /ˌsərkəmˈspekSH(ə)n/
>
> noun
>
> noun: circumspection; plural noun: circumspections
>
> the quality of being wary and unwilling to take risks; prudence.
>
> "circumspection is required in the day-to-day exercise of
> administrative powers"
>
> ~ Oxford Dictionary ([lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/definition/circumspection))